# How to escape from a rear wrist lock & twist lock

Tags: self-defense, wrist-lock

Please refer to minute 2:50 of this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3KLB8szbzw)

Following my other question [How to release yourself from back arm lock control?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/how-to-release-yourself-from-back-arm-lock-control)

Is there a way to escape from rear wrist lock & twist lock?
A video of the solution will be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't look very viable as a way of getting to that wrist lock.  Also his front leg is vulnerable while he is supposed to be in control.  I'll upload a video when I can find someone to demonstrate with.

Comment: I'd have to get a partner and play with it, but along with Huw Evans, the leg is a big problem.  The locked partner can slam his knee forward into the inside of the grabber's leg, taking out some of his balance.  It's a risk, because if they fall wrong you get your wrist tendons torn.  However, as always, there's a lot of options before that lock is fully set in, which is the better way to deal with those attempts.

Comment: @Bankuei: Do you feel like you can offer this answer?

Comment: Yeah, I just need to get some friends together to record some video.  Might take awhile - my work schedule and theirs aren't exactly matched up well.

Comment: From a Krav Maga perspective one would probably start with one, maybe multiple knees too the groin with the leg that is closer to him. Alternatively, breaking the front foot with a stamp might be a good idea. If that doesn't work I'd probably lean into him and use the front leg for a pushing judo through, maybe a harai goshi instead if he leans back. I have to admit this is quite a tricky one.

Comment: I'm no expert in joint locks, but that doesn't look so much like a tool for control as merely a way to cause pain because you control the elbow and wrist joints.  I don't see very much to actually control someone, and in exchange you've lost your arm (it's trapped between their arm and their torso) and you've got an elbow to the ribs, which is not something I'd give lightly.  His suggestion of hunkering down behind their shoulderblade also means you're not seeing anything (like a knife that might come into play)

Answer (score 2):

Usually every exercise has a solution both as an attacker or defender. The demonstration in the video shows an advantage point from the attacker, and does not focus on the defender. Thus the first thing is to **not allow yourself to get into that position**.

When you feel the opponent is grabbing onto a limb of yours, that means he/she is vulnerable somewhere. Aim for that spot.

i.e. in the video the attacker has a vulnerability on his left knee. You could try to accumulate a bit of momentum and kick his shin or knee (if you can).

Also use your body weight. Push him with your left shoulder or if he is heavier just jump onto him aiming both for the ground (I might be wrong on this one).

Again, the situation in the video *is highly advantaged* towards the attacker and you are not supposed to let anyone get that good of a hold to your arm.

I hope my answer is adequate. I am new to this community and I love to discuss Martial Arts :)

Answer (score 2):

It's true the wrist position is vunerable and can be damaged no matter what happens next.

But if I really wanted to risk it:

1. Look to slightly off balance the attacker (the guy putting the lock on) to create just enough space. I would push slightly (1 inch) with my front shoulder & front knee to my right. Then reverse this by driving with the head and torso slightly back. Repeat as required.
2. Assuming the hold is slightly loosened I can now move my hips out away from the attacker while trying to make a fist with the locked wrist.
3. Hopefully there is now a little more room and I can move my opposite shoulder forward (right one in the video), turn the hips slightly to the right & try to drive my caught wrist downwards.
4. Now that there is hopefully some space the arm that was trapped can move past the hips, I can now use my legs, head & shoulders to drive him back so that I can single leg him with the other arm.

That said I would prefer not to let the person get a hold in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One consideration the cop has to watch for is the suspect squatting down.  Yes, the cop has pain compliance on his wrist, but suspect also has his knee aimed at the cop's inside knee - that can surprise the cop enough to let go or release a little.  The cop needs to not allow his inner thigh to be so compromised on spleen 10.  It's not likely most suspects have knowledge of such pressure points, but if the suspect is panicking and flailing, that could be attacked accidentally - it is a striking point, not a rub or squeeze, so it is vulnerable.  Cop should ensure to keep suspect slightly off-balanced to the rear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO8oI1JEqHA

Suspect can also do a forward roll or a forward high fall, so the cop has to ensure to keep suspect slightly off-balanced to the rear.

Suspect can also barrel himself into the cop taking both to the ground.  If the cop is in a proper stance and suspect is slightly off-balanced rearward, that can be mitigated.

Common theme, then, is keep suspect slightly off-balanced to his rear.

Remember, no technique is fool-proof.  Every one has a weakness.